# For all $k \in \mathbb{R}$, $g'f - kf'g$ has a zero between consecutive zeros of $f$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f, g \in C^1$, $g > 0$. Suppose $f$ has consecutive zeros $a, b$. Then for any real $k$, the function
$$W_k(x) = g(x) f'(x) - k f(x) g'(x)$$
has a zero between $a$ and $b$.

This is clear from the intermediate value theorem if $f'$ is nonzero at $a, b$. But I can't seem to finish off the argument in the remaining case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Define $h(x)=g(x)^k$, and show that $$\left(\frac {f(x)}{h(x)}\right)'$$ is zero precisely 
where $$f'(x)g(x)-kf(x)g'(x)$$ is zero.

Comment: Completing the argument. By the quotient rule, the numerator of $(f/h)' = g^{k-1}(f'g - kfg')$, and since $g > 0$, this is zero whenever $f'g - kf g'$ is. By the mean value theorem, $f/h$ has a zero in $(a, b)$, and hence so does $f'g - kfg'$.

Comment: It should be $g^{-k-1}$, not $g^{k-1}$.